# can we implement accordions in emailers?

Tags: css, email, responsive-design, accordion, html-email

I'am developing an emailer based on a desktop design.

The problem is that the design has an accordion.

I am unable to find a solution on how to make accordion work on emailers.

Can it be done and will it work across all devices.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you define "emailer" ? Are you asking about the e-mail newsletter sent to clients?

Comment: yes, which will be viewed on different email clients across devices

Comment: According to my experience and personal search - newsletters (mailings) are supposed to be build using html 4 specification, created on tables with inline css styles or <style> tag in the body. Creating an accordion would require you to define at least a hover effect. But Hover effects are not supported in Outlook 2007/2010, Gmail, iOS or Android. So according to my experience - No. Don't do accordions or any complicated css creations in your newsletters. Or it will fail on some devices / e-mail providers